hide-ifdef-mode not automatically loading header files
I have a test.c file like this:
#include <stdio.h>
    
#include "test.h"
    
int main()
{
#ifdef HUHU
    printf("HAHA\n", x);
#endif
#ifndef HUHU
    printf("HAHA\n", x);
#endif
}

and the header file test.h like this:
#ifndef TEST_H_
#define TEST_H_
    
#define HUHU 1
    
#endif // TEST_H_

Opening only the test.c file and using M-x hide-ifdef-mode and M-x hide-ifdefs results in this:
#include <stdio.h>
    
#include "test.h"
    
int main()
{
#ifdef HUHU...
#endif
#ifndef HUHU
    printf("HAHA\n", x);
#endif
}

This is because the #define macro in the header file is not
automatically loaded. Only if the header file test.h is opened and M-x hide-ifdef-mode and M-x hide-ifdefs is run there, the macro is evaluated and loaded into hide-ifdef-env.
Running hide-ifdef-mode and hide-ifdefs can be automated, however the resulting hiding when test.c is opened is rather confusing. At first the #ifdef HUHU part is hidden, then when the test.h file is visited M-x hide-ifdefs needs to be run again in the test.c buffer to hide the #ifndef HUHU part and show the #ifdef HUHU part.
If M-x hide-ifdefs is forgotten, hide-ifdef-mode will hide the wrong part of the code. This hinders that this mode is something that is always activated like a global mode or in c-mode hooks.
I would like to ask if this is a bug or if this is expected behavior. Should hide-ifdef-mode evaluate included header
files? The commentary talks about this:
;; Currently recursive #include is not yet supported, a quick and reliable 
;; way is to let the compiler generates all the #include-d defined macros 
;; into a file, then open it in Emacs with hide-ifdefs (C-c @ h). 
;; Take gcc and hello.c for example, hello.c #include-s <stdio.h>: 
;; 
;;   $ gcc -dM -E hello.c -o hello.hh 
;; 
;; Then, open hello.hh and perform hide-ifdefs.

But what I understand by recursive #include is #include directives inside header files. So that the preprocessor includes a header file into a C file and inside that header file there is another #include directive which leads to another include of a header file, into the C file ultimately.
